# Bootstrap adjust the height of images in a grid

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm using bootstrap to create a grid with image with the same height. The images have a ratio depending on what box they are in, so for example the images in a col-sm-2 will have the ratio 800x800 and in col-sm-3 the images will be 1200x800.

The problem is that everything works fine but only without the padding, I presume the padding is considered as the width so the height of the image will get adjusted.

```
// Adjust the result-screen if you are getting big images (it is responsive).

http://jsfiddle.net/s00uajfw/14/
```

How is it possible to give the images the same height, keeping the 15 margin and without adjusting the ratio of the images?

Comment: Please make it more clear what you want, add a code snippet in the question instead of only in a jsfiddle. Also `.no-padding .col-sm-2,.col-sm-3 ...` removes the padding from all `.col-sm-3` not only the ones inside a `.no-padding` to do that write `.no-padding .col-sm-2, .no-padding .col-sm-3 ...`

Comment: Made a little mistake in jsfiddle but it should be fixed now: http://jsfiddle.net/s00uajfw/14/. jsfiddle contains all the code, so I don't see the point in putting it here.

Comment: Adding code inside the question makes it self contained, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I think you can't solve this using Bootstraps grid as the column width includes the padding. This makes the content area of the `.col-sm-3` not 1.5 times as wide as the `.col-sm-2`. One solution might be to create your own grid for this (perhaps using flexbox), but that will never align to the grid column and gutters of Bootstrap's grid.